# Adding a ssd to Asus N71JQ

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, asus-laptop

I have had a Asus N71JQ for a few years. I was thinking of putting in an ssd drive in the hopes of speeding it up.

Does anyone know if this laptop supports sata? I ask this because I googled for "Asus N71JQ ssd" and I got a youtube video of this guy taking apart the laptop just to add sata support.

Is there really no support for sata (which I believe is where ssd connects) in this laptop? This laptop isn't very old I assumed this would support ssd.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that machine has SATA and IIRC there was even a version available with a ssd. Anyway, installing an SSD shouldn't be a problem.

Read more here:
http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N71Jq/specifications/